# How to detect whether a function's window doesn't exist anymore

Tags: javascript, iframe

Let's say I have a variable `V` in a browser window `A`. From this window I open a new window `B` (or an iframe) that has a function `F`. In there I assign `V` to `F`. I close window `B` and then in window `A` I call `V();`.

Different browsers will behave differently and some will be throwing exceptions, especially, if function `F` tries to work with DOM elements of its own window.

I don't want that to happen and would like to check if I can call `V` or not.

My question: is there some way to have a prior knowledge that the function code is in a window that has been already closed?

Comment: I´m not sure I´m following you due to some complexity of your example. My understanding is that you´re trying to communicate different portions of code between iframes, or windows, until what I know that´s not possible.

Comment: That is absolutely possible until windows stay open. Just like calling a function from another window/iframe. My issue is about calling such a function that is in a closed window/iframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can track window state using `unload` event:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',newwin);
function newwin() {
 var newwin=window.open('');
 newwin.addEventListener('unload',lostwin);

}

function lostwin() {
 console.log('window closed');   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8uCVr/

so you can know what window is closed and let your application know if it should not expec window to be closed, if it is not enough, please give jsfiddle with example.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about it. This involves having an additional code for handling window closing and whatnot. I am wondering if there is a more general solution to it, as in: I have a function on my hands and I need to know if it is "safe" to call it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.closed` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.closed) of the `Window` object which might be closed to check whether it is still available or not.

```
if (!B.closed)
    V();
```

Comment: That's a solution. Thanks. But what if I don't know whether `V` points to a function that is in another window/iframe or it's in the same one? In other words all I have is a function and no other references.

Comment: No, there is no possibility to check whether a given function refers to corrupted data. If you need it in a single function, then you will need to perform the test inside it - you could wrap the original F when assigning it to V (instead of `V = B.F` do `V = function(){if (!B.closed) return B.F();}`).

Comment: Thanks! In my case it's `A.V = F` inside window `B` and then I call `V` from inside window `A`. Maybe I should rethink the design.